# How to hide and disable Wordpress admin menu items

Tags: wordpress

I have two Wordpress Administrator accounts but I need to hide certain admin menu items for one admin. I've out found how to do this but how can I disable directly accessing the page by url? Something like this [Advanced Access Manger](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/)

So far I have..

```
function hide_menu() {

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if($user && isset($user->user_login) && 'admin2' == $user->user_login) {
        
        remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' ); //Plugins
        remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); //Tools
        remove_menu_page( 'users.php' ); //Users
        
    }
    
}

add_action('admin_head', 'hide_menu');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Solution:**
You can use this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/prevent-direct-access/

**Coding Solution:**

```
    add_action('template_redirect', function() {
        // ID of the page you want to restrict from
        if (!is_page(2072)) {
           return;
        }

        // Provide the link of admin dashboard, so that page should only 
       // accessible 
      //  through admin dashboard
        if (wp_get_referer() === 'https://example.com/wp-admin/') {
            return;
        }

       // we are on restricted page
       // visitor is trying to access directly
        // so redirect to home
       wp_redirect(get_home_url());
        exit;
    } );
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I'm trying to deny one admin from accessing certain menu items in the admin panel, like the Advaned Access Manager plugin. I would just buy that but I need to use it for many sites.

Comment: Well I thought you sorted out the restricted access as you have mentioned in your question, So I just told how to restrict direct access, combining both approaches may solve your problem